# How to retrive json data from sql table column into as a separate table

Tags: sql, json

I have customer table with columns names
"orderid",
"body",
"time",

Below is the JSON data in side "body" column: `{"PersonTitle":"Mr","FirstName":"david","LastName":"ford","PhoneNumber":""}`.

How do i get the select data with column names orderid,firstname,phonenumber?

Comment: What SQL flavour are we talking?

Comment: sql server 2016

Answer (score 0):

*you should persist can come from an external source or generated through serialization from instances of objects.For sample;*

```
 foreach (var c in countries)
    {
  // Serialize the C# object to JSON
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c)
  // Save content to the database
  record.JsonColumn = json;
}
```

*You can use Entity Framework (ORM), as well, to save JSON data into one column of a database table. For sample;*

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json='{"PersonTitle":"Mr","FirstName":"david","LastName":"ford","PhoneNumber":"":["SQL","C#","MVC"]}';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json);
```

Comment: Thank you @mutlu .I have table with values already ,i just want to query the  data using select statement in sql query